# Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java (Maven) keeps dropping application.properties file

Tags: spring-boot, eclipse, maven, spring-tool-suite, application.properties

As I'm working on a project, with automatic reloads on save on, sometimes Eclipse will just stop loading the application.properties file for whatever Maven project I'm working on. Usually this happens generally the same time the automatic reloads stop upon making changes to the application.properties file. The biggest headache is getting Eclipse to start picking up the file again, as cleaning the project, closing/opening the editor, making random meaningless code changes here and there, all don't work.  I have to do something random like unconfigure a massive portion of my project or delete a big chunk of the pom.xml and try to run the project again (if it works).  I'm just spending a significant amount of time trying to get Eclipse to stop behaving so erratically on a regular basis.  Thanks for you help!

- Closing/Opening editor
- Cleaning/Rebuilding project
- Making meaningless code and configuration changes, and trying to compile
- Forcing the project to completely choke and then fixing the introduced errors

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and tell the version of your Spring Tools plugin and of your Eclipse.

Comment: I am not sure I understand the problem description clearly enough, but it reminds me of https://github.com/spring-projects/sts4/issues/929 (which is fixed in STS 4.18.0 and the latest m2e release).

Comment: @Martin Lippert I found the solution in that link you posted. Apparently in my case Eclipse will randomly decide to start ignoring the files in src/main/resources (the files in the folder don't have to change in my case) and the problem is fixed by using **Run As => Maven Install**  If I could give you credit for solving the issue I would. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I found to my unique case is in the comment posted by Martin Lippert in the comments [on this page](https://github.com/spring-projects/sts4/issues/929). the issue was that Eclipse was randomly deciding to stop using things in the **src/main/resources** folder.  This was fixed using **Right Click => Run As => Maven Install** on my application